# Django/pyodbc error: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: sql-server, django, pyodbc

I have a Dictionary model defined in Django (1.6.5). One method (called get_topentities) returns the top names in my dictionary (entity names are defined by Entity model):

```
def get_topentities(self,n):
        entities = self.entity_set.select_related().filter(in_dico=True,table_type=0).order_by("rank")[0:n]
        return entities
```

When I call the function (say with n=2), it returns the top 2 elements but I cannot access the second one because of this "not enough arguments to format string" error:

```
In [5]: d = Dictionary.objects.get(code='USA')
In [6]: top2 = d.get_topentities(2)
In [7]: top2
Out[7]: [<Entity: BARACK OBAMA>, <Entity: GOVERNMENT>]
In [8]: top2[0]
Out[8]: <Entity: BARACK OBAMA>    
In [9]: top2[1]
.
.
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_pyodbc/compiler.pyc in         as_sql(self, with_limits, with_col_aliases)
172         # Lop off ORDER... and the initial "SELECT"
173         inner_select = _remove_order_limit_offset(raw_sql)
--> 174         outer_fields, inner_select = self._alias_columns(inner_select)
175 
176         order = _get_order_limit_offset(raw_sql)[0]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_pyodbc/compiler.pyc in _alias_columns(self, sql)
339 
340                 # store the expanded paren string
--> 341                 parens[key] = buf% parens
342                 #cannot use {} because IBM's DB2 uses {} as quotes
343                 paren_buf[paren_depth] += '(%(' + key + ')s)'

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

In [10]:
```

My server backend is MSSQL and I'm using pyodbc as the database driver. If I try the same on a PC with engine sqlserver_ado, it works. Can someone help?
Regards,
Patrick